# Ubuntu apt-get upgrade breaks update-initramfs?

Tags: ubuntu, initrd, lilo, initramfs-tools

I ran `apt-get upgrade` on a Ubuntu 8.04 32-bit server. It upgraded lots of packages but failed here:

```
Processing triggers for initramfs-tools ...
update-initramfs: Generating /boot/initrd.img-2.6.24-16-server
update-initramfs: lilo run failed for /boot/initrd.img-2.6.24-16-server:

Warning: LBA32 addressing assumed
Fatal: raid_setup: stat("/dev/sda")
dpkg: subprocess post-installation script returned error exit status 1
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (2)
```

The only hard drive in the system is `/dev/hde` and apparently `update-initramfs` is trying to find `/dev/sda`.

Now I'm afraid that the system won't boot the next time I start it. Any idea how to solve the problem? Please let me know if you need any additional info.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Apparently the solution was to run `apt-get remove lilo`.

This way, it doesn't need to upgarde the relevant packages anymore.

Pleane note that Lilo still functions as the boot loader, it just uninstalls the installer/bootstrapper of Lilo.

Answer (score 1):

Do you have a backup initrd.img-2.6.24-16-server in /boot? If so, compare the size of the two. Are they different? You could try replacing the new one with the backup and see if it boots then. That worked for me after an update (GUI) on an old Ubuntu desktop (8.04) of mine broke my initrd.img. I might be way off base, but if your system won't boot it could be worth a try.